# Jquery text editor hangs the browser when writing big text data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, rich-text-editor, jqte

I'm using jquery text editor [jqte](http://jqueryte.com/) to allow users to edit content of some text areas. Whenever I add large text to the editor the browser hangs for a while then after few seconds (sometimes 1 minute) it comes back to live again then it hangs again when you are scrolling or editing. I mean with the browser hangs is that you can't do anything to the page, you can't click any buttons or even scroll down or up in the page. I tried to put some large text in their [online demo](http://jqueryte.com/demos) and this behavior happens. Is it a bug or just there is some parameter tuning that could solve the issue ?

> **Note**: I didn't put any code snippets because using this editor is quite
>   simple and the behavior happens even on their online demo